# Fabric check user has permissions on file/folder

Tags: python, fabric

Is there an equivalent in fabric to `os.access('/path/to/folder', os.W_OK)` to check whether a remote folder has correct permissions given an remote user/group?

Currently I could try getting into the folder with `with cd` and catching the exception but I dont like that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `os` lib for obvious reasons; but you can use [test](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test). I made a quick 2-min example on how to use it.

```
from fabric.api import env, task, run, sudo as _sudo, settings, hide

env.user = 'vagrant'
env.key_filename = '~/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'
env.host_string = '127.0.0.1'
env.port = '2222'


def is_file_writable(filepath, sudo=False):
    fn = run if not sudo else _sudo
    with settings(warn_only=True), hide('everything'):
        response = fn('test -w ' + filepath)
        return response.return_code == 0


@task
def sometask():
    print is_file_writable('/etc/sudoers')
    print is_file_writable('/etc/sudoers', sudo=True)
```

output:

```
$ fab sometask
False
True

Done.
Disconnecting from 127.0.0.1:2222... done.
```